# storing USERID in sessions?

Tags: php

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['Email']);
    $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['Password']);

    if (empty($Email)) {
        array_push($errors, "Email is required");
    }
    if (empty($Password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }


if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $Password = md5($Password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email' AND Password='$Password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($database, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);


 if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;

                $UserID = $row['UserID'];
                $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;

    header('location: Home.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong Email/Password combination");
        }
```

i am able to get the Email stored in sessions but i can not get the UserID. can i also use the userID stored in sessions to add to a form?

Comment: do not md5 your passwords. use `password_hash` and `password_verify`!

Comment: can you show how you try to get the userID out of $_SESSION?

Comment: and have you verified that you get a `$row['UserID']` out of database?

Comment: and finally: please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You can store whatever you like in a session

Comment: after 2 hours no response?

Comment: hi jeff... this is how i get the userID .                                                       <p> Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['UserID']; ?></strong> </p> .                so when the log in button is clicked and you are directed to the home page, it should show welcome [UserID] but it doesn't